# Show that $\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

### Problem

> Show that $\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$.

Can someone please verify my solution attempt?

### Solution

Given functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, $f(n)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $g(n)$ if and only if:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1.$$

Let $f(n)=\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$ and $g(n)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$.

By Stirling's formula, $n!$ can be expressed as:

$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\epsilon(n)}$$

where

$$\dfrac{1}{12n+1}\leq\epsilon(n)\leq\dfrac{1}{12n}.$$

So, $f(n)$ may be rewritten as:

$$\begin{aligned}
    f(n)&=\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\\
    &=\dfrac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\dfrac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n} e^{\epsilon(2n)}}
    {2^{2n} 2\pi n\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{2n} e^{2\epsilon(n)}}\\
    &=\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{2n} e^{\epsilon(2n)}}
    {2^{2n+1} \sqrt{\pi n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{2n} e^{2\epsilon(n)}}\\
    &=\dfrac{e^{\epsilon(2n)}}{ e^{2\epsilon(n)}\sqrt{\pi n}}
\end{aligned}$$

So, since both $\epsilon(n)$ and $\epsilon(2n)$ approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$, we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\dfrac{e^{\epsilon(2n)}}{ e^{2\epsilon(n)}\sqrt{\pi n}} \cdot \sqrt{\pi n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{e^{\epsilon(2n)}}{ e^{2\epsilon(n)}}=\dfrac{\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\epsilon(2n)}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{2\epsilon(n)}}=1,$$

as required.

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: It would be a bit faster using explicitly the asymptotic equivalents provided by Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok, but it would be simpler using $n! \sim  \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n$ which implies
$$ (2n)! \sim  \sqrt{4\pi n} (2n/e)^{2n}=2 \,\sqrt{\pi n} \,4^n (n/e)^{2n}$$

and
$$ (n!)^2 \sim  2\pi n  \, (n/e)^{2n}$$

Now

$$\begin{align}
 \dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}&= 
\frac{1}{4^n} 
\dfrac{(2n)!}{ 2 \,\sqrt{\pi n} \,4^n (n/e)^{2n}}  \left(2 \,\sqrt{\pi n} \,4^n (n/e)^{2n}\right)
\dfrac{2\pi n  \, (n/e)^{2n}}{(n!)^2} \dfrac{1}{2\pi n  \, (n/e)^{2n}}\\
&= 
\dfrac{(2n)!}{ 2 \,\sqrt{\pi n} \,4^n (n/e)^{2n}} 
\dfrac{2\pi n  \, (n/e)^{2n}}{(n!)^2}
 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n  } }\\
\end{align}$$

where the two first fractions tend to $1$ as $n\to \infty$.
Hence

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2} \sqrt{\pi n }=1$$